# Can I create a MYSQL TRIGGER WITH or condition in TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, triggers, database-schema

Can I create a **MYSQL** TRIGGER With OR Condition

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TIGGER NAME 
BEFORE INSERT **OR** UPDATE **OR** DELETE

LIKE this (below is an ORACLE TRIGGER):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGERNAME_XYZ
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON TABLE_NAME_ABC
REFERENCING OLD as OLD NEW as NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
mAppUserCode     VARCHAR2(50);
mOSUser          VARCHAR2(100);
mAppUserName     VARCHAR2(100);
mModuleName      VARCHAR2(100);
mChangeID        NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT APP_USERCODE, OS_USER, APP_USERNAME, MODULE_NAME INTO mAppUserCode, mOSUser, mAppUserName, mModuleName FROM DB_SESSION_VIEW;
SELECT CHANGE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO mChangeID FROM DUAL;
IF INSERTING THEN
   :NEW.CREATED_BY_MODULE     := mModuleName;
   :NEW.CREATED_BY_USER_CODE  := mAppUserCode;
   :NEW.CREATED_BY_OS_USER    := mOSUser;
   :NEW.CREATED_BY_USER_NAME  := mAppUserName;
   :NEW.CREATED_ON            := sysdate;
   :NEW.CHG_ID                := mChangeID ;
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
   :NEW.CHANGED_BY_MODULE     := mModuleName;
   :NEW.CHANGED_BY_USER_CODE  := mAppUserCode;
   :NEW.CHANGED_BY_OS_USER    := mOSUser;
   :NEW.CHANGED_BY_USER_NAME  := mAppUserName;
   :NEW.CHANGED_ON            := sysdate;
   :NEW.CHG_ID                := mChangeID ;
END IF;
END;
/
```

In **MYSQL** is it possible to create a TRIGGER With OR Condition??

Also from phpmyadmin there is no option in the event section to add the or condition ie to select **INSERT ,UPDATE AND DELETE**
there is no provision to put **BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE**
So my question is that is it possible like the above Oracle trigger?
[image]

Comment: try it once and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL doesn't provide multiple event for single trigger. What you can do it. You just create one `procedure` and in that procedure wrote whole this logic as it is.

Put NEW and OLD value as a parameter to that procedure.

And call that procedure from all three trigger.